# C++ Exception Handling In Base Class

Tags: c++, inheritance, exception

Supposing I have some general Application class definition which contains:

```
class Application{
    public:
    void Run(){
        try{
            ....
        }catch(const Exception& ex){
            ....
        }
}
```

Now supposing I inherit Application from class App1:

```
class App1: public Application{
    void Run(){
        Application::Run();
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to catch the exception in the base class? I tried the above and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using virtual function, like this:

```
    class Application{
    public:
    virtual void DoRun() {
    ....
    }
    void Run(){
        try{
            DoRun();
        }catch(const Exception& ex){
            ....
        }
}

class App1: public Application{
    virtual void DoRun() {
        Application::DoRun();
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would make `DoRun` protected, to emphasize that `Run` is the one outside code should be using.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. By the time you `throw ex;` in `App1:Run()`, `Application::Run()` has already finished running.